# Assigning object IDs with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Suppose I have a client side app that sends out requests to a rails back end. One of those requests would to create a new object, say a Post. In this case the client side app sends in a json request containing a post title and the post content.

But now suppose that the object needs to have an id as well, which the client side app doesn't provide. Is there a way for rails to automatically increment the previously created post's id and set the newly created objects id to this value?

Would I put this into the `create` method of PostsController? Or does this sort of logic belong in the model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is done at the database level. The tables rails generated for you will by default have an auto incrementing id column